# how can I scan live mp3 streams for their sample rate?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, icecast, sample-rate

I am new to FFMPEG and I am suppose to scan all of my files for sample rate. I am not sure as to what this is because I am new to this and don't know how to even get started with FFMPEG's scanning. These live streams are mp3 streams, music tracks. I am familiar with PHP if that makes any difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140085/how-to-get-sampling-rate-and-frequency-of-music-file-mp3-in-android

Is a good start.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "live streams"?  I thought you had a bunch of files?

Comment: I emailed your email with the url of live streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call FFMPEG with an input file, it will show you all of the data related to each stream:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp3
```

There is a separate executable typically bundled with FFMPEG though that does what you need, and that is `ffprobe`.  So on a Windows system, you would do something like this to redirect its standard output to a file:

```
ffprobe -i yourfile.mp3 -show_streams > file_stream_info.txt
```

In that file, you'll find something like this:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mp3
codec_long_name=MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=1225/32
time_base=1/14112000
start_time=0.000
duration=210.688
nb_frames=N/A
[/STREAM]
```

All you have to do then is use whatever scripting language you're using (PHP?) to split this up into key/value pairs (read lines and run [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on them).  I should also note that in most languages, there is a method to read standard output from something you're executing without writing a file, which will be far more efficient.

Comment: Brad I just emailed you something, Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **code**

`$var = shell_exec("mpg321 -t my_file.mp3 2>&1 | grep Hz | awk '{print $7}'`

Comment: I think you are confusing bitrate and sample rate, sample rate is sampling frequency.