# how to get channel count of audio file

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to retrieve the channel count of a .wav sound file using `TrackInfo` and `MediaFormat` but I cant seem to get a handle of a `MediaFormat` object which i believe would provide the channel count.

I have tried following this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25784226/1463931) but it is not helping.

here is what I have so far

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundPath);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    TrackInfo info = mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo()[0];
    MediaFormat mf =
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `MediaExtractor` and `MediaFormat` to access the `KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT`

Here is an example,

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(path);
//where path is a String variable and points to the data source
MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
//where i is an int variable and denotes the index value of a track.
//For the first track: i = 0; 
int count = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
```

I would also recommend reading the example in `MediaExtractor` Class Description from Android Developer Reference. Here is the link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html

I hope this helps. Happy coding.