# Get frequency from a song android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how can i get frequency from a song file through android. I can get only bitrate and song format, but not frequency.

```
CompatMetadata data = new CompatMetadata(path);
        format=decodeMimeType(data.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE));
        bitrate = Integer.parseInt(data.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE))/1000;
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140085/how-to-get-sampling-rate-and-frequency-of-music-file-mp3-in-android

Comment: i know how to get bitrate, actually that solution of getting bitrate is not accurate, my example works better. i need frequency

Comment: You know frequency changes throughout the song, right? Unless the thing you want to achieve is sampling rate...

Comment: yeah, i need sampling rate