# Get information about audio file in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I want load an audio file (wav or mp3) from the file system and display audio information, such as sampling rate etc.

How can I do this? Do you know any examples?

Comment: You may want to use a third party Java library to do that. You can use `AudioManager` to get information like Artist and Album.

Comment: Isn't there any library from Android itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate it by dividing the file size by the length of the audio in seconds, for instance, from a random AAC encoded M4A in my library:

```
File Size: 10.3MB (87013064 bits)
Length: 5:16 (316 Seconds)
Which gives: 87013064 bits / 316 seconds = 273426.147 bits/sec or ~273kbps
Actual Bitrate: 259kbps
```

Since most audio files have a known set of valid bitrate levels, you can use that to step the bit rate to the appropriate level for display.

[Link to original answer by Jake Basile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140085/how-to-get-sampling-rate-and-frequency-of-music-file-mp3-in-android)

Or use this code to get it much more accurate:

```
MediaExtractor mex = new MediaExtractor();
try {
    mex.setDataSource(path);// the adresss location of the sound on sdcard.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

MediaFormat mf = mex.getTrackFormat(0);
int bitRate = mf.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE);
int sampleRate = mf.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
```

[Link to original answer by architjn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140085/how-to-get-sampling-rate-and-frequency-of-music-file-mp3-in-android)

Comment: Thank you so much. The second example was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It it possible to use java.media on Android? You can do that with some classes in java.media also.